# Unable to scroll in WPF textblocks using ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, textblock

I have 2 textblocks on my form. I need to have vertical scrollbars in each of them. Due to some reason, I am not able to get the scrollbars on both. Kindly provide me with some idea.

```
    <Grid>
    <Button Content="COMPARE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.351,-2.164" Height="242" Width="226" Loaded="TextBox1_Loaded" />
    <ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.351,-2.164" Height="242" Width="226" Loaded="TextBlock1_Loaded" />
    </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.351,-2.164" Height="242" Width="226" Loaded="TextBox2_Loaded"/>
    <ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.351,-2.164" Height="242" Width="226" Loaded="TextBlock2_Loaded_1"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Content="EDIT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <Button Content="HOME" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.23,0.986" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WPF - ScrollViewer + TextBlock troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981137/c-sharp-wpf-scrollviewer-textblock-troubles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check this out:
1. XAML Code:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock  x:Name="ATextBlock" ></TextBlock></ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="BtTextBlock" ></TextBlock></ScrollViewer>
```

the problem was; the Height definition on the TextBlock. Just remove it and that is.

regards.,

Comment: @ShellyTomar you're welcome, feel free to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

To show vertical  scroll bar on a TextBox when needed you can use this XAML

```
<TextBox .... VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

ScrollBar will apear when text does not fit the original space given to controll.

Comment: I have scrollbars in textbox. I need vertical scrollbar in textblock.

Comment: then look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981137/c-sharp-wpf-scrollviewer-textblock-troubles